# WebSockets on iOS: keep the connection live

Tags: javascript, ios, websocket

Is there a way to keep the websocket connection live on iPhone Safari browser?
After a few seconds( around 30 I think) if the screen is not touched, the display turns off and the wesocket connection is closed.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to send messages to keep the connection alive or use something like socket.io that allow you to reconnect automatically.

Of course that kind of things are to reduce the number of kb transfer and optimize the battery.

If its an App you could use VOIP Push Notifications to start the socket again/send the message but if its the browser just reconnect or send messages to keep the connection live.

Comment: hello. I've tested this by sending a websocket message every 10 seconds and still the connection is dropped

Comment: Are you definitely connected at the other end?